# what this query has error?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

i wrote this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src ="../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js"> </script>
   <script type = "text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#btnhide").click(function(event){
    $("a").slideUp(1000);
    });
    });
</script>
```

but it has following error.

```
Edit: i sure that jquery is loaded successfully.



 Error: $ is not defined
    Source File: http://localhost:1416/my362/ControlPanel.aspx
    Line: 36
```

what is problem?

```
Edit: i sure that jquery is loaded successfully.
```

Answer (score 3):

you forgot to include jquery

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: He didn't ... forget ... presumably he just gave an incorrect relative URI ;-) But yes, using a CDN is usually a good choice (although the link given is for 1.5, not 1.4.1 and, while it would be nice if jQuery never broke backwards compatibility...)

Comment: [Downloading jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#CDN_Hosted_jQuery) lists the current "offcial" CDNs; I am not sure where the historical CDNs are documented.

Comment: quite welcome :) I had no idea it existed and was shocked when I found it a while back XD

Answer (score 2):

jquery isn't loaded, check ../Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js if is correct

try to replace `$` with `jQuery` in your code to be sure.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that the link to the `jquery-1.4.1.min.js` is correct. You get that error when the JQuery is not found.